# Count against undisplayed detail

Tags: business-objects

So in my Desktop intelligence report, I have detail from my universe that can can have many different double digit response codes ("00","01","02",etc, etc) per a terminal.  What I am trying to do is count all of the response codes that are not "00" at the terminal level without having to display the Response Code.

I have tried the following:

```
=CountAll (If (<Response Code> = "00") Then 1 Else 0) ForEach( <Response Code> ) 

=CountAll (If (<Response Code> = "00") Then 1 Else 0) In Report
```

Using a ForEach will always equal 1 and using the In Report statement will always come back with 237!  Anybody have an idea of what i'm missing?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways:

First, create a variable, let's call it `<Non Zero Response>`:

```
=If <Response Code> <> "00" Then <Response Code>
```

Then in the report block:

```
=Count(<Non Zero Response>)
```

The second method works, but I'm not sure why.  So I can't be sure it will work in all versions:

```
=Count(=If <Response Code> <> "00" Then <Response Code>)
```

Comment: This ended up working

=Count(=If <Response Code> <> "00" Then<Response Code>)

however, when i try to add a second condition to the If statement, I get a syntax error.

Comment: Just found it!  Was trying to use a measure.  Made it a dimension and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Yeah, I should have mentioned that.  But it should have detected it as a dimension anyway.